# Chrome Developer Tools search not finding existing text

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

When **searching for strings in Chrome Developer Tools** during development, I encounter totally erroneous behavior in Chrome 31.0.1650.63. Some **existing text is simply not found**. I can see no pattern at all and found nothing in Google.

This is a static html page, no DOM manipulation.

Searching for "pay" yields partial, erroneous results:

[image: Search for "pay"]

**Update:** It seems that the search is *partially* case sensitive. Searching for "Pay" hits everything while searching for "pay" only hits "Pay"s when they are behind a special character (and not an alphabet letter).

[image: Search for "Pay"]

I am relying heavily on that search, and I am shocked that something so elementary seems to be buggy. Surely I am missing something. But what?

Comment: This is true as of version 32, still. Very annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a Chrome v.32 bug. Upgrading to 33 beta solved it for me.

Comment: That's it - my Chrome had already updated itself to version 33, and now it works.